# iPhone Sencha Touch- How to add table views to the split view in sencha touch

Tags: iphone, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have implemented `Tabbar` in sencha touch without any content as follows:

using code

```
Ext.ns('sink', 'demos', 'Ext.ux');
Ext.ux.UniversalUI = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,
                                {
                                  fullscreen: true,
                                  layout: 'hbox',
                                  items:

                                  [
                                     //Root view 
                                     {
                                       xtype: 'panel',
                                       html: 'TableView/Rootview goes here ...',
                                       flex: 1
                                   },

                                    //Details view
                                   {
                                       xtype: 'panel',
                                        html: 'Message Detail view goes here ....',
                                       flex: 2
                                   }
                                  ]

                                });
```

But I need two `Tableviews` one as `Rootview` and the other as `Detailsview` as follows

Comment: Kitchen Sink Demo: User Interface -> List view ... http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/kitchen-sink

Comment: when i use any code for list simulater shows only white blank screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Ext.List](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List). So instead of your left panel (commented as //Root view), you can add this :

```
{
  xtype:'list',
  id: 'navigation',
  data: [
    { title: 'Page 1'},
    { title: 'Page 2'},
    { title: 'Page 3'},
    { title: 'Page 4'},
    { title: 'Page 5'}
  ],
  itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('{title}'),
}
```

I let you guess what you have to do for the second view ;)

Hope this helps

Comment: when i use any code for list simulater shows only white blank screen

Comment: Try to change the layout of your panel from hbox to fit